# How to select all field in all tables from a MySQL in talend

Tags: mysql, talend

I am looking for a way to select a full MySQL database in talend and use it as source to generate an XML.

Currently I'm trying with the `tMysqlInput` component but I can only select individual table. I've 10+ table and I want to rebuilt my data with several `tMap`. So I'm looking for a component or way to get the full database in one shot.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you need one `tMysqlInput` per table. That's the Talend logic.

What I suggest you to do :

1. Retrieve all table schemas using Talend
2. Drag & Drop the created schema to the Talend Designer and select `tMysqlInput`
3. Your newly `tMysqlInput` should already be set to use the corresponding schema (repository mode)
4. If you press "Guess query" in the `tMysqlInput` settings, it will list all columns

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, take a look at the `tMysqlTableList` https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/7.65+tMysqlTableList

**EDIT**

Talend can make JOINs directly in the tMap component. A good example can be found here : http://techblog.appirio.com/2009/12/performing-lookups-and-transformations.html

Comment: (full comment)
thanks Jean-Michel. I will give it a try. 

However if all tables are in a separate tMysqlInput, how does Talend will get relation between them? I want to get my full database into an xml feed (I guess that should have been my first question).

Comment: thanks. That's what I thought ... quite a painful process might go for a php script to generate the xml file out of the database.